# EF6: Renaming namespace using Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, namespaces, entity-framework-migrations

It is possible for me to rename  the namespace of my entire Project (including of course: DbContext class, Migrations configuration classes, etc) without breaking anything or having to recreate all my migrations?

Say, I have Project MyProject, which namespace is

```
Foo.MyProject
```

And my configuration classes are in

```
Foo.MyProject.Migrations
```

Say I want to rename **Foo** namespace for **Bar**, and of course my Configurations namespace now will be

```
Bar.MyProject.Configurations
```

Is there any correct way of doing this and maintain all my current Migrations still working?
Do these ways involve manually editing the ___MigrationHistory table or something? (at a glance I see the ContextKey column, which I suspect I should manually edit.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you do indeed need to update the ContextKey in the__MigrationHistory table. Code:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] 
   SET [ContextKey] = 'New_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration'
 WHERE [ContextKey] = 'Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration'
```

A good read on the topic of renaming namespaces with EF6:

http://jameschambers.com/2014/02/changing-the-namespace-with-entity-framework-6-0-code-first-databases/

Comment: Whoa. Exactly what I needed! Thanks.