# Changing namespace of my DbContext inherited class causes Invalid OperationException. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created my models using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model (and chose Code First from database) since I am making a project on an already existing database and everything worked fine, I was able to access the data in the db. However, I tried to rearrange my namespaces, by creating a Data Access Layer namespace for my class that inherits from DbContext. However, when I do this, I get an `InvalidOperationException` was unhandled error when I try to use the exact same code otherwise that says: `The model backing the 'RaaSDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database`. Does anyone know why this is happening? I have not changed the class's values or anything else (literally just the namespaces), so don't know why this is no longer working.

Code Before:

```
namespace MyProject.Model
{
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext ()
            : base("name=MyConnection")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<MyClass> MyClass{ get; set; }
        etc...
    }
}
```

Code changed was only on the first line:

```
namespace MyProject.DAL
```

Code that was calling db:

```
using MyProject.DAL; //This line was also added on the code change
using MyProject.Model;
etc...
MyDbContext DBContext = new MyDbContext();
List<string> myStrings = DBContext.MyClass
            .Select(a => a.myStrings)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run migration, Entity Framework create a  table with the name **___MigrationHistory**.
In this table EF have all those stuff that need to be updated when you make some changes in the context.

So for that we have migration commands. To know more about migration command please [follow this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj591621.aspx)

In this _MigrationHistory table, EF also have namespace as contextkey column. So if you make changes in the namespace then you should also manage this stuff.

For your reference please [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547450/ef6-renaming-namespace-using-code-first-migrations)

So in these scenario you have two options to go forward

a)  Run a Sql Command

```
UPDATE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
   SET [ContextKey] = ‘New_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration’
 WHERE [ContextKey] = ‘Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration’
```

b) You should be golden at that point, however, this won’t work if you’re doing continuous integration with a team of developers, or if you have a continuous deployment strategy in place. For that, the solution lies in adding the following code to your database Configuration constructor class:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    this.ContextKey = “Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration”;
}
```

Part of the solutions is taken from [here](http://jameschambers.com/2014/02/changing-the-namespace-with-entity-framework-6-0-code-first-databases/)

Comment: I understand they are not in sync, and could run code-first migrations in theory, but I do not understand why changing the namespace would make them out of sync in the first place.

Comment: @AlanSchapira entity framework set the namespace in _migration table in databse as contextkey. So you have to update that too if you are changing namespace

Comment: @AlanSchapira http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547450/ef6-renaming-namespace-using-code-first-migrations

Comment: Ah perfect! That makes sense. Am I best off changing the contextkey manually in the db, doing a migration, or can i just delete the migration table?

Comment: @AlanSchapira Two options as i know..updated in the answer. hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i am right, but i think you should never modify the namespace on your own. You should never modify those auto generated files on your own in general.

But i think there is an option to archieve what you want: [have a look at this example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f457d4b5-ab07-4a0e-8b2c-2bfa17ba7257/ef4-how-to-changedefine-the-c-namespace-of-the-generated-code-in-designer-file?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

You should modify the custom tool namespace. Hope it works!

Comment: The example you have sent me is for the option EF Designer from database. I chose the Code First from database option. Sorry for not specifying, but i changed the questions now!